# Posting data from express node to mongodb using angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi I am building an app using the mean stack, with an angular controller which loads the initial data successfully. However when a user is added it attempts to post the user object to the server side, however "/api/contacts" returns an error 500, **(TypeError: undefined is not a function)**. Code is below:

//complete error message :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at module.exports.postcontactlist (/Users/Sites/express/api/contacts.js:22:11)
    at callbacks (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Users/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:48:5)
    at next (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.urlencoded [as handle] (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:46:27)
    at next (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at /Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:91:7
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:57:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
POST /api/contacts 500 4ms - 1.69kb
```

**//server.js routes**

```
var contactlist = require("./api/contacts");
...
app.get("/api/contacts", contactlist.getcontactlist);
app.post("/api/contacts", contactlist.postcontactlist);
```

**///api/contacts.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var bp = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var schema = require("../models/contactsdb"); 

var Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", schema.contactSchema, "contactlist");

    module.exports = {

        getcontactlist : function (request, response) { 

            Contact.find({ }, function (err, docs) { 
                response.send(docs);
            });

        },

        postcontactlist : function(request, response){

    console.log("request: " + request.body);

    Contact.insert({ "name" : "Vincent Moyet", "email" : "vincentmoyet@gmail.com", "number" : "0987654321" }, function(err, docs){

        if(err){

            var errorMsg = "error: " + err.message;
            console.log(errorMsg);
            response.status(500).send(err);

        } else {
            console.log("success");
            response.status(200).end();
        }
    });
}

    };
```

Can someone enlighten where im going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm posting another answer as the question author has rewritten their question - @learningAngularIsFrustrating: you should really have written a new question rather than make such large edits to your original one]

What is the code on line 2" ((/Users/Sites/express/api/contacts.js:22:11)? I guess it is the `insert` and think you may be better off with `save` (that's what I use in a similar situation to yours).

```
var contact = new Contact({ "name" : "Vincent Moyet", "email" : "vincentmoyet@gmail.com", "number" : "0987654321" })
contact.save(function(err, docs){...});
```

Comment: Hi Simon H, apologies Im still relatively new to Stackflow.
I have tried ".save" instead of ".insert", however receive the same exact error message.

Comment: OK. But can you check which function it is not finding by looking at the line numbers in the error message

Comment: I've done just that, however cannot identify the reason why its not working unfortunately, besides Im still a novice in node express.

Comment: have a go with my new suggestion above

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked!!! However with my code I found I can use the static "create" method. Its great as I now understand both methods.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not reporting the success back to the client

```
   postcontactlist : function(request, response){

        Contact.insert(request.body, function(err, docs){
                    if(err){
                       console.log("error: " + err.message);
                 --->  response.status(500).send(err)
                   } else {
                       console.log("success");
                 --->  response.status(200).end()
                   }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hi Simon H, I have updated my code with your suggestion, and added a screenshot of what is being posted. Im even now directly inserting the object . However still returning a 500 error status.

Comment: What message are you getting in the node consle. I don't think this is an angular issue but that your server is not working for some reason and posting pictures from the client side will not help

Comment: Hi Simon H, ive updated the main post, now includes the full error stack. Had a look at https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues/100 . However, still unable to identify the source of the error.